# Carbon get quarter of the year

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get my data quarter based so for each year I will have 4 variable like `pastYearsQOne` `pastYearsQTwo` `pastYearsQThree` `pastYearsQFour`.

My question is **how can I get quarters of the year?**

`code`

```
$pastYearsQOne = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereDate(
  'created_at', '<=', now()->subYear(1)->startOfQuarter()->toDateTimeString()
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
)->count();
```

If still didn't get it! here is the logic,

Final result will be like:

```
$pastYearsQOne = data of: 2020 (year) -> 01~03 (months)

$pastYearsQTwo = data of: 2020 (year) -> 04~06 (months)

$pastYearsQThree = data of: 2020 (year) -> 07~09 (months)

$pastYearsQFour = data of: 2020 (year) -> 10~12 (months)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startOfQuarter` and `endOfQuarter` quarter are useful, along with `month` function.

Please try using the below code.

```
$startOfQ1 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(1)->startOfQuarter();
$endOfQ1 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(1)->endOfQuarter();

$startOfQ2 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(4)->startOfQuarter();
$endOfQ2 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(4)->endOfQuarter();

$startOfQ3 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(7)->startOfQuarter();
$endOfQ3 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(7)->endOfQuarter();

$startOfQ4 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(10)->startOfQuarter();
$endOfQ4 = Carbon::now()->subYear()->month(10)->endOfQuarter();
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to fix my issue, here is my final code `$pastYearsQOne = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereBetween(
            'created_at', [Carbon::now()->subYear(1)->month(1)->startOfQuarter(), Carbon::now()->subYear(1)->month(3)->endOfQuarter()]
        )->count();`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean ?

```php
public function index()
{
    $now = Carbon::now()->subYears(1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $pastQuarterOneStart = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarters(3)->startOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-01-01 00:00:00
    $pastQuarterOneEnd = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarters(3)->endOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-03-31 23:59:59

    $pastQuarterTwoStart = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarters(2)->startOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-04-01 00:00:00
    $pastQuarterTwoEnd = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarters(2)->endOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-06-30 23:59:59

    $pastQuarterThreeStart = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarter(1)->startOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-07-01 00:00:00
    $pastQuarterThreeEnd = Carbon::parse($now)->subQuarter(1)->endOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-09-30 23:59:59

    $pastQuarterFourStart = Carbon::parse($now)->startOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-10-01 00:00:00
    $pastQuarterFourEnd = Carbon::parse($now)->endOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2020-12-30 23:59:59


    // Get 2020-01-01 00:00:00 to 2020-03-31 23:59:59
    $pastYearsQOne = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            $pastQuarterOneStart,
            $pastQuarterOneEnd
        ]
    )->count();

    // Get 2020-04-01 00:00:00 to 2020-06-31 23:59:59
    $pastYearsQTwo = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            $pastQuarterTwoStart,
            $pastQuarterTwoEnd
        ]
    )->count();

    // Get 2020-07-01 00:00:00 to 2020-09-31 23:59:59
    $pastYearsQThree = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            $pastQuarterThreeStart,
            $pastQuarterThreeEnd
        ]
    )->count();

    // Get 2020-10-01 00:00:00 to 2020-12-31 23:59:59
    $pastYearsQFour = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            $pastQuarterFourStart,
            $pastQuarterFourEnd
        ]
    )->count();
}
```

Here I also change the query based on the data you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a variable for current year `Carbon::today()`
then recursively add 3 months for all quarter `Carbon::addMonths(3)`